# How to make DeckGL-like 3D columnLayer map at country level in QGIS or Illustrator?

Tags: qgis, 3d, mapping, 3d-map, illustrator

I have data for a series of points around the continental U.S.

Using deck.gl, I can turn this point data into a nice 3D [ColumnLayer](https://deck.gl/docs/api-reference/layers/column-layer) map.

[image: Map made with deck.gl]

Now I'm trying to find a way to make a similar map, but for use in a print publication. My normal workflow is to make maps like that in QGIS, export them to SVG, then refine them in Illustrator.

But I haven't been able to find a way to recreate this specific mapping technique using QGIS.

In theory, a [3D Map View](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/map_views/3d_map_view.html) with a [3D "cylinder" symbol](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/3d_symbols.html) should work.

But in practice, it doesn't. The `length` and `radius` fields seem to allow a maximum value of 100,000, which is nowhere near tall enough for a map showing the continental U.S.

[image]

Even if that wasn't an issue, QGIS doesn't allow you to use a formula to set the height on 3D symbols. So I'd have to create individual rule-based styles for each of the 200 points, which is nuts.

Finally, I may be mistaken, but it seems like a 3D map view can't be exported in a format Illustrator could open, anyway.

Now, if I export just the flat map with points as an SVG and open it in Illustrator, I could extrude the points within Illustrator. But there I run into the same problem again -- I have to manually set the length of each of the new cylinders individually. (And if I could get that working, I'm not sure how to move the cylinders and underlying basemap into the proper perspective.)

Anyway, just wondering if anyone else has successfully produced maps like this for print use, in QGIS or Illustrator or something else. If so, what techniques and tools did you use?

Comment: Try https://minorua.github.io/Qgis2threejs/docs/ExportUsingProcessingAlgorithm.html